# Adding unique info windows to markers and updating a database to store the info (google map api)

Tags: javascript, php, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am currently coding a travel website that will allow a user to click on a map, resulting in a marker going into that location. From here I wish for the user to apply an info window to that particular marker with details such as Country, City, Duration, Comments. However when I code this, the info window will appear but the data is not unique, the data the user enters and saves shows over the next marker the exact same. So for example, say the user clicks Ireland, when they click England, and go to edit that marker the marker will have all the Ireland information in it. How do i make this unique?

here is my HTML code:

```
function initialize() {
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(54.5, -7.0);
  var options = {
    zoom: 7,
    center: latlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), options);
  var html = "<table>" +
             "<tr><td>Country:</td> <td><input type='text' id='country'/> </td> </tr>" +
             "<tr><td>City:</td> <td><input type='text' id='city'/></td> </tr>" +
             "<tr><td>Duration:</td> <td><input type='text' id='duration'/></td> </tr>" +
             "<tr><td>Category:</td> <td><select id='category'>" +
                "<option value='city' SELECTED>City Break</option>" +
                "<option value='beach'>Beach Holiday</option>" +
                "<option value='romantic'>Romantic Holiday</option>" +
                "<option value='activity'>Activity Holiday</option>" +
                "<option value='site'>Site Seeing</option>" +
                "</select> </td></tr>" +
             "<tr><td></td><td><input type='button' value='Save & Close' onclick='saveData()'/></td></tr>";
infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
 content: html
});

google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", function(event) {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: event.latLng,
      map: map
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });
});
}

function saveData() {
  var country = escape(document.getElementById("country").value);
  var duration = escape(document.getElementById("duration").value);
  var category = document.getElementById("category").value;
  var latlng = marker.getPosition();

  var url = "phpsqlinfo_addrow.php?country=" + country +  "&city" + city + "&duration=" + duration +
            "&category=" + category + "&lat=" + latlng.lat() + "&lng=" + latlng.lng();
  downloadUrl(url, function(data, responseCode) {
    if (responseCode == 200 && data.length >= 1) {
      infowindow.close();
      document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "Location added.";
    }
  });
}

function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
  var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
      new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
      new XMLHttpRequest;

  request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (request.readyState == 4) {
      request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
      callback(request.responseText, request.status);
    }
  };

  request.open('GET', url, true);
  request.send(null);
}

function doNothing() {}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Reinitialize the infowindow content when you create a new marker:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", function(event) {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: event.latLng,
      map: map
    });
    infowindow.setContent(html);
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {

      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });
});
```

Comment: that got rid of that problem thanks, however now what is happening is when i click on the marker again, it displays the infobox of the most recent marker? how do i stop this so that it only opens the marker infobox that i click on

Comment: That is another question. Either save the data associated with each marker so it can be re-displayed when it is clicked or remove the marker when you submit the information to the database.

Comment: sorry i am a bit of a novice, how would i go about saving the data so it can be re-displayed?

Comment: That is another question.

Comment: One that you are unable to answer? or even point me in the right direction?